How to use Apps Scripts to restrict Google Forms Input based on available stock in a spreadsheet?
I’m working in a company that manages its operations using Google Sheets. We have a form used to request products from another sector, where users must no be able to request quantities greater than the available in the stock.
I’m trying this using Google Apps Script, but it's challenging.
Here's an example of the form and spreadsheet:


Manipulating the spreadsheet is easy, for example, I got the product names and quantities added to a map with this code:
/**
 * Retrieves stock data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet and returns it as a dictionary (map).
 *
 * @returns {Object} A dictionary where keys are product names and values are quantities in stock.
 */

/**
 * Retrieves stock data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet and returns it as a map.
 *
 * @returns {Map} A map where keys are product names and values are quantities in stock.
 */
function getStockMap() 
{
    // Spreadsheet ID
    const spreadsheetId = "1J5twCP4L4Smy7FP4JbARD3qVB_mv8rnQ1fRN5y6LvaQ";

    // Open the spreadsheet
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);

    // Get the "Stock" sheet
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Stock");

    // Define the range of cells containing stock data
    const range = sheet.getRange('B1:D8');

    // Get the values from the range
    const data = range.getValues();

    // Create an empty map to store stock data
    const stockMap = new Map();

    // Iterate through the data and populate the stock map
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        const product = data[i][0];
        const quantity = data[i][2];
        stockMap.set(product, quantity);
    }

    // Log the stock map
    for (const [product, quantity] of stockMap) 
    {
        Logger.log(`${product}: ${quantity}`);
    }

    return stockMap;
}


Upon searching I found this relevant SO question: How to restrict google forms submission based on two ID using GAS on Google Form or Google Sheets
However, I don't want to use the "OnSubmit" trigger because I'd submit the form with the wrong data all the same.
@ziganotschka mentioned google docs on how to programatically add text input validation to form (here, but it seems you need to create a field to do this, but I'd need to ADD validation to an existing field)
Any help is appreciated, this is my 3rd day at work, I am a python dev, never touched JS. Another issue is that Google's documentation appears to tell you all functions available without very useful examples, guides or explanations of why things are as such. Maybe I'm dumb, but I had issues with Google documentation in the past, I find it very hard to parse, so I am asking for help.

With formSubmit trigger for the form you could remove the incorrect form response and with the formSubmit trigger you  could remove the incorrect sheet response.

My guess is that using an html form would probably  be the easiest way  to go.

@Cooper I was thinking about that too, but I have a feeling that they don't want to change their infrastructure for a while. Everything relies on Google Sheets. and I mean, everything.
I was dealing with Google Sheets APIs until 2 months ago in my last job, but we had Data, business logic and the user's front end all decoupled from another. I did stuff more complex than this in just a couple hours, but with everything in a spreadsheet and a very limited API to manage it, it's become much more challenging.

Good morning!
Could you update automatically a data validation on the quantity requested item?


// Add a text item to a form and require it to be a number within a range.
var textItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Pick a number between 1 and 100?');
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText('Input was not a number between 1 and 100.')
  .requireNumberBetween(1, 100)
  .build();
textItem.setValidation(textValidation);



https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation
You could run this function on the onOpen(e) trigger for the form.
However, this will always apply the same data validation, whatever which product was selected.
A workaround would be to create sections, each product would have its own "Quantity requested" section with its custom data validation. The navigation will allow you to direct the user to the right section depending on the product he selected. You could use the snippet above to define every data validation for each section.
Hope this helps!

I'm checking this up @Lidia. I was thinking about modifying an existing field, but maybe that won't be possible, so I'm trying alternatives like this one. Thanks.
